# How does Tornado print request information like Python SimpleHTTPServer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado, simplehttpserver

How does Tornado print request information like Python SimpleHTTPServer?

IP/Date/Way/Router/HTTP Version/Status

[image: Similar to this (Python SimpleHTTPServer)]

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `log_function` keyword argument to the `Application` constructor to customize logging output. This is [documented with the rest of the Application `settings`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.Application.settings).

Alternately, you can subclass `Application` and override the `log_request` method.